# Can Virtual Event Handlers Cause Any Problems

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, virtual

Are there any gotchas with registering virtual methods as event handlers as opposed to registering a private method that delegates to a virtual method?  I would prefer Option 1 (which seems to work), but I want to make sure it's not going to bite me later.

**Option 1**

```
public class Controller1
{
    public Controller1(EventNotifier eventNotifier)
    {
        eventNotifier.ImportantEvent += OnEventNotifierImportantEvent;
    }

    protected virtual void OnEventNotifierImportantEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
public class Controller2
{
    public Controller2(EventNotifier eventNotifier)
    {
        eventNotifier.ImportantEvent += eventNotifier_OnImportantEvent;
    }

    private void eventNotifier_OnImportantEvent(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        OnEventNotifierImportantEvent(sender, eventArgs);
    }

    protected virtual void OnEventNotifierImportantEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just don't ever raise the event in the constructor. This goes for calling any virtual method in the constructor, not just raising events. The reason is that objects are instantiated, and constructors executed, in a top-down fashion, while virtual methods are basically resolved bottom-up. While the code for the virtual method is easily found, if it's called in a constructor, the most derived implementation may rely on state data that simply doesn't exist yet, because the object hasn't been fully instantiated.

What the second option does basically fools refactoring assistants like ReSharper, so they won't flag the "virtual call in constructor" as a problem; the call in the constructor is not virtual, and unless it's smart enough to trace through (most aren't), it won't bat an eye at the cascading virtual event. However, there would still be a problem if the event (either one) were raised from the constructor.

Beyond that, no problems I know of.

Comment: Good point about potentially calling a virtual method from the constructor, but both of those options have the potential to call a virtual method in the end.

Comment: +1 for the explaining the top-down execution of virtual methods and their dependency on state data.